# How can I store the previously rendered from from an OpenGL Fragment Shader for later use?

Tags: opengl, glsl, fragment-shader, framebuffer

I'm writing a FFGL video effect plugin (using [this](https://github.com/leadedge/ShaderMaker) shadertoy port). I want to store a previously rendered frame to use in a future calculation. Specifically I am trying to make the equivalent of a video delay.

Is it possible to write to an external buffer from a fragment shader and then use that stored value at a later time (say, 30 frames later)?

Comment: Of course. Render to texture and then use the texture as input.

Answer (score 1):

you create a FBO, and bind it. whatever you render next goes onto it. so if you're using a shader, that still applies like on the default FBO.

here's some code to help you out

```
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL14.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL30.*;

public class FBO {
    public int fbo,tex,depth;

    public void delete() {glDeleteTextures(tex);glDeleteRenderbuffers(depth);glDeleteFramebuffers(fbo);}
    public void bindTexture() {glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex);}
    public void bind() {glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo);}
    public static void unbind() {glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,0);}

    public FBO(){ // create the fbo
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex=glGenTextures()); // create texture, set correct filters
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP);

        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,depth=glGenRenderbuffers()); // create buffer for depth

        glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,fbo=glGenFramebuffers()); // create framebuffer
        glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0,GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex,0); // attach texture
        glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT,GL_RENDERBUFFER,depth); // attach depth
        unbind(); // incase not using immediately
    }

    public void resize(int w,int h) {
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,tex); // update texture size
        glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,GL_RGBA8,w,h,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,(ByteBuffer)null);
        glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER,depth); // update depth size
        glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER,GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24,w,h);
    }

    public void render() {
//      glColor4f(1,1,1,1); // you may want to do these customly
//      glDisable(GL_BLEND);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, tex);
        Tess.begin();
        Tess.vertex(    0, height, 0, 0, 0);
        Tess.vertex(width, height, 0, 1, 0);
        Tess.vertex(width,      0, 0, 1, 1);
        Tess.vertex(    0,      0, 0, 0, 1);
        Tess.draw();
        // Tess btw, just manually handles verts and tex coords
        // that could be pure pipeline, or by vbo / vao / interleaved vbo
        // width / height are just the 2d size. could render for post processing
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you!

Follow up question. If I want to have the texture only filled every n-frames, is there a way to have the shader know how many frames it has been since it last wrote to a texture?

i.e. the effect i'm working on will need the delay value (in frames or time) parameterized. The effect will use that stored texture on every pass in the shader BUT will only set the shader after n-frames.

Comment: sounds like you just want to limit the fps rendering to the fbo. right?

Comment: if you was only wanting to draw every n frames, you could simply do, n++; n%=10 (or whatever); if(n==0) draw. i dont think you can actually just tell opengl to do this. you'll have to manage that in your actual language.